# How do I push an update to my internal testers on the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I feel like I am missing something that should be obvious, but how do I push an update to my testers on my internal test release? I am not seeing a way to upload a new app-bundle as I was able to do for the initial version (1.0.0).

*Release management > App releases*
[image: Release management > App releases]

*Release management > App releases > Internal test track > Release: 1.0.0*
[image: Release management > App releases > Internal test track > Release: 1.0.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press on **Create release**, upload your new .aab file and submit internal test version. Clicking on Internal test section you may also modify your testers group by clicking on **Manage testers** section. If your testers don't see the update try to send them an opt-in URL to let them subscribe to the updates by looking under the same **Manage testers** section.

Comment: How much time does it take to push an update? I've been waiting more than an hour for an update to get pushed as of this writing.